# Ponteiro Inválido

Tags: visual-studio

Tenho um projeto em `Asp.Net MVC` com `Entity Framework 4.5`, que criei limpo, mas ao tentar criar uma `View` recebo o seguinte mensagem:

**Erro** :

> There was an error running the selected code generator : 'Ponteiro
>   inválido (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004003 (E_POINTER))'

Você também pode visualizar o erro clicando [aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP2jJ.png).

Procurei algo com o código apresentado, mas não encontrei nada.

**Versão utilizada :**

```
Community 2015 v 14.0.24720.00 Update 1.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema estava sendo causado por alguma extensão, fiz a remoção e reinstalação de algumas delas, além da reinstalação do Visual Studio, e tudo passou a funcionar normalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Para a correção do problema citado apenas foi necessária a reinicialização do Windows! Tentei reiniciar o Projeto, o Visual Studio 2015 e não adiantou. Só ai que percebi que existia uma **atualização do windows 10**, pois, já aconteceram outras vezes da atualização do windows bugar o Visual Studio.

Minha sugestão seria:

- Verifique se existe atualização do windows.
- Atualiza e reinicie o windows.

Answer (score 0):

Com o Visual Studio fechado, delete todos os arquivos que estão dentro do seguinte diretório: **%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache**.

Provavelmente irá funcionar novamente.